# Limting Characters In 2 Separate Text Fields Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitextfield

In my app, I have 2 text fields. taskTextField and DescTextField. I would like to limit the characters of the task text field to 15 and the description text field to 20. I have managed to limit both but I don't know how to do them separately. Here is my code for both:

```
let limitLength = 20

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= limitLength
}
```

Any help on how to make separate limits for each text field would be appreciated.

Comment: check which text field is being referred to by the argment `textField` to the function

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a tag for each `UITextField`:

   ```
   let taskTextFieldTag = 100
   let DescTextFieldTag = 101

   override func viewDidLoad() {

        // ..

        taskTextField.tag = taskTextFieldTag
        DescTextField.tag = DescTextFieldTag

        // ...
   }
   ```
2. In the `UITextFieldDelegate`:

   ```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       guard let text = textField.text else {
           return false
       }

       let newLength = text.utf16.count + string.utf16.count - range.length

       var maxLength = 0

       switch textField.tag {
       case taskTextFieldTag:
            maxLength = 15
       case DescTextFieldTag:
            maxLength = 20
       default: break
       }

       return newLength <= maxLength
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code assuming you can connect the text fields to your code via IBOutlets

```
    @IBOutlet weak var taskTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descTextField: UITextField!

    let taskTextFieldlimitLength = 15
    let descTextFieldlimitLength = 20

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        switch textField {
        case taskTextField:
            guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
            let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
            return newLength <= taskTextFieldlimitLength
        case descTextField:
            guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
            let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
            return newLength <= descTextFieldlimitLength
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
```